# UIAppearance BarButtonItem with Rounded Corners

Tags: ios

For some reason when I apply a background image to a UIBarButtonItem it makes the corners sharp rectangles. How can I fix that using the UIAppearance?

```
 // bar button
    id barButtonAppearance = [UIBarButtonItem appearance];
    [barButtonAppearance setBackgroundImage:[theme imageForBarButtonNormal] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

-(UIImage *) imageForBarButtonNormal
{
    return [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_button_item_blue_background"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image needs to have rounded corners. This is the same way that interface elements are done behind the scenes in iOS.